# How to do multiple actions from a single link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I have banner image that I want to link to an external site while recording user clicks into a clicks table and adding a point to that user's points in the users table.

How can I make the link_to image to do that?

For now, my code is below, but it doesn't redirect because I put the external URL in the controller. Also it doesn't call the users controller to record the points because I don't know how to call multiple actions using "link_to.. do end":

#### index.html.haml

```
= link_to image_tag("http://res.cloudinary.com/../image.jpg", size: "100%", class: "img-fluid"), clicks_path(id: current_user.id, image_source: "abc"), method: :post, remote: true
# user_add_point_path(point: 2)
```

#### clicks controller

```
def create
  @click = current_user.clicks.create(user_id: params[:id], image_source: params[:image_source])
if @click.save
  if params[:image_source] == 'abc'        
    redirect_to abc.com
```

#### users controller

```
def add_point
  @user.increment!(:point)
```

Comment: you can use java-script in this case, just call app method by link_to and for that link_to event create a js event and based on that event you can open external link to new tab

Answer (score 0):

You can't do multiple actions per one link click. Not with native click handling anyway.

Two approaches here:

1. Handle click on your banner with javascript. Intercept the event, cancel its propagation (`e.preventDefault()`) so that browser doesn't follow the link. Then perform your actions by manually calling necessary urls with jquery or something. When you're done registering clicks and adding points, navigate to the needed page by assigning `window.location.href`, for example.
2. Handle all the clicks and points accounting in the same single action on the server. At the end of that action, redirect.

I'd go with option 2.

Answer (score -1):

This can help you. Just change your code according

```
= link_to image_tag("http://res.cloudinary.com/../image.jpg", size: "100%", class: "img-fluid"), 
          "your/url/path", id: current_user.id, image_source: "abc", 
          method: :post, remote: true
```